# AngularJS pass state param to data field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I pass the site_id parameter to pageTitle from data ?

```
.state('site', {
   url: "/site/:site_id",
   templateUrl: "views/site_detail.html",            
   data: {pageTitle: 'Site :' + $scope.$state.params.site_id},
   controller: "SiteDetailController"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could use `resolve`:

```
.state('site', {
    url: '/site/:site_id',
    templateUrl: 'views/site_detail.html',
    controller: 'SiteDetailController',
    resolve: {
        pageTitle: function($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.site_id;
        }
    }
);
```

Then, your controller would look like:

```
app.controller('SiteDetailController', function($scope, pageTitle) {
    console.log('pageTitle = ' + pageTitle);
});
```

Resolve is useful if you plan on retrieving or processing data based on the parameters prior to completing the state change. If you're only interested in the parameter value, then you can use `$stateParams` in your controller:

```
app.controller('SiteDetailController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log('pageTitle = ' + $stateParams.site_id);
});
```

**Update**: [Here is a CodePen with an example using both `$stateParams` and `resolve`.](http://codepen.io/caroach1080/pen/epEXNB)

Comment: <title data-ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle"></title> This is how I use the pageTitle, and it's not showing up here.

Comment: data : {
                pageTitle: function($stateParams) {
                    return $stateParams.site_id;
                }
            }, this doesn't work either, it gives me <title data-ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle" class="ng-binding">function ($stateParams) {
                    return $stateParams.site_id;
                }</title>

Comment: If you're only trying to get the params, you could just include `$stateParams` in your controller. Then you can set a scope variable with something like: `$scope.pageTitle = $stateParams.site_id;`

Comment: I've added a CodePen example.